# MongoDB does not find replica set configuration file

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm configuring a MongoDB with ReplicaSet.

If I startup the mongo (Docker image mongo5:0) and execute inside the container

```
rs.initiate({
 _id: "replicaset",
 members: [
   {_id: 0, host: "host1"},
   {_id: 1, host: "host2"},
   {_id: 2, host: "host3"}
 ]
})"
```

everything works correctly.

However, if I try to set the configuration automatically using a file in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` I get the following error

`Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup`

I'm not using any configuration file, I'm just initializing things as in the snippet but I've read that both approaches should be the same. Is there something that I should know about the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` approach that I'm doing wrong?

If I'm forced to use that configuration file, where should it be placed within the mongo container?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an _error_ as opposed to an informational message? My recollection is that any uninitialized `mongod` process will report this prior to the `.initiate()` command being executed. Also keep in mind that "document" is NOT "file"

Comment: You were right, It was an info message, my error was something else. However, now I'm getting an authentication error. I'm setting the user password in my connection string, after creating the user, but I'm getting a user not found problem. I think the problem is related with the authentication setup not being correct since I had to delete the --auth in my initialization command (the docker was just disappearing if I kept It ). Maybe there is a new way of telling Mongo to use authentication, in Mongo5, that has changed with the upgrade from versión 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that is not posible to ser up a replica set on the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d fólder

So, preparing the Mongo without replica set at startup and running the command to initiate it worked.

But it needed not to be done at the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d step